# Perl Unescaped left brace in regex issue - nagios check_multi

Tags: regex, perl, nagios

I'm trying to run a nagios check script called check_multi that runs fine under older versions of Perl but not newer. I get the message
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated here (and will be fatal in Perl 5.30), passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^${ <-- HERE NAGIOS}/ at ./check_multi line 1519.

The line is

```
push @result, "$key=$ENV{$key}" if ($key=~/$pattern/);
```

and I've tried changing it to

```
push @result, "$key=$ENV\{$key}" if ($key=~/$pattern/);
```

But even with the \ before the { i still get the error -

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is in the value of `$pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

Change line to :

```
push @result, "$key=$ENV{$key}" if ($key=~/\Q$pattern/);
```